# Change hidden_field_tag name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**_form.html.erb**

```
<% @subjectmodulelists.each_with_index do |modules,index| %>
     <%= hidden_field_tag 'subjectModuleId'+index.to_s, modules.subject_module_id%><%= f.submit class:"btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The above code I have in partial form actual field name was subject_module_id in my db. Here i changed to 'subjectModuleId'+index.to_s for store array of data.

I have following Error.

> Mysql2::Error: Field 'subject_module_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `term_questions`

**Params passes Like:**

```
"subjectModuleId0"=>"65",  "subjectModuleId1"=>"66", "subjectModuleId2"=>"67",
```

**In my controller**

```
@question = TermQuestion.new
@question.subject_module_id = params[:subjectModuleId]
```

How I change the name into subject_module_id.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `'subject_module_id[]'` which accepts array of values

Answer (score 0):

Pass array value to the hidden field

```
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'subject_module_id[]', @subjectmodulelists.map(&:subject_module_id) %>
  <%= f.submit class:"btn btn-primary" %>
```

This way you will get params like

```
{ "subject_module_id"=>[65, 66, 67] }
```

Which then you can assign

```
@question.subject_module_id = params[:subject_module_id]
```

Comment: "subject_module_id"=>["65 66 67", "65 66 67", "65 66 67"] its return like this. @Deepak Mahakale

Comment: May be because you are still looping over `@subjectmodulelists`